# Get very last character of a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following URL which I'm fetching:

```
http://domain.com/search/?wpv_paged_preload_reach=1&wpv_view_count=1&wpv_post_id=205499&wpv_post_search=saint%20laurent&wpv_filter_submit&wpv-women-clothing%5B0%5D=all-clothing
```

The following code manages to get the whole URL

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');
```

My question is, how can I get the last Character of the above URL, so that I can test a condition like this:

```
if (last character in code containers an integer) {
    do something
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The answer you have linked to does not answer the queston. The jquery locaton.href doens't return the parameters passed, sdo you need to use window.location.search instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example using `charAt` method:

```
url.charAt( url.length - 1 )
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `substr()` for this.

```
var url = 'http://example.com/something2';
url.substr(-1); // 2
```

To check if it's a number:

```
if ( !isNaN(url.substr(-1)) ) {
  // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
var lastChar = $(location).attr('href').charAt( $(location).attr('href').length - 1 )
```

or like this :

```
var lastChar = $(location).attr('href')[$(location).attr('href').length - 1];
```

or in a simple way like this

```
var lastChar = $(location).attr('href').substr(-1);
```